# How to implement login-specific behaviour throughout an application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, vaadin

I have an web application that should only differ in one point: if a user is logged in, the data should automatically be saved to a DB.
Non-logged in users should be able to use the full application, but without persistence.

How could one implement this best through the whole application?
Would I have to call some `Session.getUser.isLoggedIn()` before every action that could potentially trigger a persistence action? That's what I came up so far.

Or are there better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having to write such behavior in single place would be the best approach.

That can be accomplished in variety of ways and depends on what is your technology stack.

Whats your front end? whats your persistence framework?

Lets say you are calling a Stateless session bean for persistence. you can put an interceptor before that, which would check for logged in user before proceeding.